# SQL Query Dynamic PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

I have temporary table with following structure:

```
MONTH  ID           CNT
-----  -----------  ---
4      TOTAL_COUNT  214
5      TOTAL_COUNT  23
6      TOTAL_COUNT  23
4      FUNC_COUNT   47
5      FUNC_COUNT   5
6      FUNC_COUNT   5
4      INDIL_COUNT  167
5      INDIL_COUNT  18
6      INDIL_COUNT  18
```

How i can get the Pivot over month in this table like:

```
ID           APRIL  MAY  JUNE 
-----------  -----  ---  ----
TOTAL_COUNT  214    23   23
FUNC_COUNT   47     5    5
INDIL_COUNT  167    18   18
```

Please consider this table format. I am little messy in posting this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can use a **Static Pivot** - one that you hard-code the months.  In the comments, you stated that the number of months maybe be unknown, if that is the case then you will want to use a **Dynamic Pivot** to generate the list of months.  Using a Dynamic Pivot gives you the flexibility of not knowing the columns you need until you run it.

```
create table t
( 
    [month] int, 
    [id] nvarchar(20), 
    [cnt] int 
)

insert t values (4,'TOTAL_COUNT',214)
insert t values (5,'TOTAL_COUNT',23)
insert t values (6,'TOTAL_COUNT',23)
insert t values (4,'FUNC_COUNT',47)
insert t values (5,'FUNC_COUNT',5)
insert t values (6,'FUNC_COUNT',5)
insert t values (4,'INDIL_COUNT',167)
insert t values (5,'INDIL_COUNT',18)
insert t values (6,'INDIL_COUNT',18)

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(month) 
            FROM t 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select month, id, cnt
                from t
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 sum(cnt)
                for month in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)

drop table t
```

The results would be:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bluefeet. It's just solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'll leave the conversion of month integers to month names to you, but this will perform the PIVOT for you.

```
declare @t table
( [month] int, [id] nvarchar(20), [cnt] int )

insert @t values (4,'TOTAL_COUNT',214)
insert @t values (5,'TOTAL_COUNT',23)
insert @t values (6,'TOTAL_COUNT',23)
insert @t values (4,'FUNC_COUNT',47)
insert @t values (5,'FUNC_COUNT',5)
insert @t values (6,'FUNC_COUNT',5)
insert @t values (4,'INDIL_COUNT',167)
insert @t values (5,'INDIL_COUNT',18)
insert @t values (6,'INDIL_COUNT',18)

SELECT 
    [id], [4], [5], [6]
FROM
    (SELECT [month], [id], [cnt] FROM @t) src
PIVOT
    (SUM([cnt]) FOR [month] IN ([4], [5], [6])) p
```

Comment: On second thought, you just need `SELECT [id], [4] as [April], [5] as [May], [6] as [June]` !

Comment: Thanks for your answer i was expecting simillar kind of answer But the [MONTH] field is flexible so the Select statement is always giving the constant results the month value can be JAN,FEB March also.How can i generate those dynamically

Comment: Dynamic PIVOT is a much more complicated thing to do. If you are not confident with PIVOT then I would strongly suggest against dynamic PIVOT - it involves dynamic SQL and is a big headache. Normally this is a reporting or visualisation requirement, so I would suggest you do this formatting in your presentation layer.

Comment: Seems a bit complex solution to me i think i need to manage this in my SSRS report only.Thanks though @Krik

Comment: If you are using SSRS then it is much preferred to do this using Column Groups.