# Convert single column with multiple rows into a single row having multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to convert a column data into single row with multiple columns

Example - I created a temp table to load data for the column

```
CREATE TABLE TestC (Comments Char(100), Row_Count [int] IDENTITY(1,1))

INSERT INTO TestC VALUES('A'),('B'),('C'),('D')

Select Min( Case When Row_Count = 1 Then Comments End ) As Comments 
, Min( Case When Row_Count = 2 Then Comments End ) As Comments 
, Min( Case When Row_Count = 3 Then Comments End ) As Comments 
, Min( Case When Row_Count = 4 Then Comments End ) As Comments 
, Min( Case When Row_Count = 5 Then Comments End ) As Comments 
, Min( Case When Row_Count = 6 Then Comments End ) AS Comments 
, Min( Case When Row_Count = 7 Then Comments End ) AS Comments 
FROM TestC
```

[image: Result]

I am trying to make it dynamic query, Below is the code snippet I am trying out currently

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR (MAX);
SELECT   @sql =  ' SELECT Min (CASE WHEN [Row_Count] =' + CAST ([Row_Count] AS CHAR(5)) + 
' THEN [Comments] END) AS Comments'
FROM     [dbo].[TestC];
SET @sql = @sql + N' FROM  [dbo].[TestC] ';
PRINT @sql
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

This still needs some tweaking. Appreciate your Help..

Comment: If i get it right you want to convert rows into columns,
then why not simply crosstab it..!!

Comment: Yes. You just need to convert from rows to columns. Let me try cross tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pivot query such as below :

```
SELECT Pvt.*
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM TestC
    )AS P
PIVOT (MIN(Comments) FOR Row_Count IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]))Pvt
```

EDIT :
You can see below links:

[Dynamic Pivot Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8327261/1407421)

[Dynamic Pivot Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10404348/1407421)

[Dynamic Pivot Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10792991/1407421)

Comment: This need to be dynamic actually.Here in the answer it is hardcoded